# ASP.NET with Telerik Controls Performance Tuning?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I am using Telerik controls in an ASP.NET Website.  It takes time while sending an Ajax request.

Is it advisable to use Telerik controls?

Do Telerik controls affect the performance of the ASP.NET website?

Please let me know tricks to identify the memory leak in an ASP.NET application, specifically in aspx.cs pages.

Comment: i think it will affect the performance,if you use Telerik control

Comment: ya but Telerik controls provide numerous server side and client side events hanlders, most pages were developed using telerik controls.i dont know how to convert all these controls with dot net contros,conversion may take long time.so i want to tune tha app,do you have any idea for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every additional control on a page will affect the perfomance. Complex controls more so than simple controls.

With the telerik controls (which also consists of complex and powerful controls like grid, editor, treeview etc), it is quite easy to badly affect performance. One of the most common causes is probably excessive ViewState.

That said, most of the time you can optimize the performance. As a starting point, search the telerik site for [performance optimization articles](http://www.telerik.com/search.aspx?insection=True&start=0&client=telerik_developer_tools&q=asp.net%2bajax%2boptimize%2bperformance). You can find some of the commmon performance optimization articles on the [support page for ASP.NET AJAX controls](http://www.telerik.com/support/aspnet-ajax.aspx) (in the section Performance). E.g:

- [Webinar series: Optimizing RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX](http://tv.telerik.com/search?q=optimizing+RadGrid)
- [Tips and tricks for performance improvements](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/top-performance.aspx)
- [Optimizing output, page load time and overall performance](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/optimizing_output_and_page_load_time_by_using_radscriptmanager_and_radstylesheetmanager.html)
- [Top 15 optimization tips and tricks in public forums](http://blogs.telerik.com/ToddAnglin/Posts/07-05-14/Top_15_Optimization_Tips_and_Tricks.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fToddAnglin%2fPosts.aspx%3fPage%3d3)